# Proguard-rules.pro failed while removing logs in relese apk Android

Tags: android, proguard

```
   ProGuard, version 5.2.1
    Note: the configuration specifies that none of the methods of class 'android.util.Log' have any side effects
    : can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl$Builder
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Call
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl$Builder
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
    Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzast: can't find dynamically referenced class android.os.SystemProperties
    Note: com.squareup.picasso.Utils: can't find dynamically referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
    Note: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule accesses a declared field 'MODULE_ID' dynamically
          Maybe this is program field 'com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.flags.ModuleDescriptor { java.lang.String MODULE_ID; }'
    Note: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule accesses a declared field 'MODULE_VERSION' dynamically
          Maybe this is program field 'com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.flags.ModuleDescriptor { int MODULE_VERSION; }'
    Note: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule accesses a declared field 'sClassLoader' dynamically
          Maybe this is program field 'com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$DynamiteLoaderClassLoader { java.lang.ClassLoader sClassLoader; }'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient { com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcn zza(android.content.Context,com.google.android.gms.common.zza); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.common.zza'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.flags.impl.FlagProviderImpl { void init(com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zzd); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zzd'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement { void registerOnScreenChangeCallback(com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$zzd); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$zzd'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement { void unregisterOnScreenChangeCallback(com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$zzd); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$zzd'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId { com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId getInstance(com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout { void setScrollableViewHelper(com.sothree.slidinguppanel.ScrollableViewHelper); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel.ScrollableViewHelper'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout { void setPanelState(com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout$PanelState); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout$PanelState'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout { void setPanelStateInternal(com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout$PanelState); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout$PanelState'
    Note: there were 2 references to unknown classes.
          You should check your configuration for typos.
          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unknownclass)
    Note: there were 3 classes trying to access generic signatures using reflection.
          You should consider keeping the signature attributes
          (using '-keepattributes Signature').
          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#attributes)
    Note: there were 8 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members.
          You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes
          (using '-keep').
          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#descriptorclass)
    Note: there were 2 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
          You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
    Note: there were 3 accesses to class members by means of introspection.
          You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned class members
          (using '-keep' or '-keepclassmembers').
          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclassmember)
    Warning:there were 318 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
             You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
             If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
             the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
             (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
    Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
    > java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    Information:BUILD FAILED
    Information:Total time: 4.766 secs
    Information:1 error
    Information:200 warnings
    Information:See complete output in console


   My proguard-rules.pro file is:
# Disable Android logging
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontobfuscate
-forceprocessing
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontnote android.support.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn org.apache.lang.**
-dontwarn android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn com.android.volley.toolbox.**
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}
-keep class * extends android.app.Activity

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {*;}
```

I addded this code to remove logs from app-release apk and getting this errors like IOException and in this please correct above warning first. I don't know how to correct this warnings. I refer many links but still I can't able to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this in proguard.pro file.

```
-dontwarn com.squareup.**
-dontnote com.squareup.**
```

Comment: still there are errors..plz help me.Thank you for answer..i post next qustion which are errors plz find it..

Comment: write same line to remove all warning and note in progaurd.pro file with packagename. like this 

-dontwarn com.dropbox.**

Comment: Thank you Rims..it works for me..there are no warnings now..but the issue is still i can see Logs in release apk..what can i do to remove all logs in release apk??can you suggest me any help??

Comment: -assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
  public static *** d(...);
  public static *** w(...);
  public static *** v(...);
  public static *** i(...);
}

Comment: i added this lines into my proguard-rules.pro file:
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
public static *** d(...);
public static *** w(...);
public static *** v(...);
public static *** i(...);
public static *** e(...);
}  but still displaying logs of D and E..

Comment: Make sure your proguard configuration does not have -dontoptimize in it. It's the proguard optimizer that removes method calls that have "no side effects".

The SDK default proguard-android.txt has -dontoptimize in it. Use proguard-android-optimize.txt instead, and don't add -dontoptimize in your project-specific proguard configuration.

Comment: Other option is press ctrl+R in your project,find Log.d or whatever you want and replace with comment line add near log.

Comment: but i want this logs in debug apk and want to remove it into release apk..i edit my build.gradle file with 
 buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'enableCrashlytics', 'true'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'enableCrashlytics', 'false'
        }
    } this..but i got 11 errors and build failed..

Comment: Make sure your proguard configuration does not have -dontoptimize in it. It's the proguard optimizer that removes method calls that have "no side effects". The SDK default proguard-android.txt has -dontoptimize in it. Use proguard-android-optimize.txt instead, and don't add -dontoptimize in your project-specific proguard configuration.Have u seen this.

Comment: Thnks a lot..i check all 3 files and use 'proguard-android-optimize.txt' file in gradle relese type and i now i can't show any logs into release..thank you rims once again..it works like charm..i am happy..:)Thank you for ur help.

Comment: No issue.Thanx Grishma :)